# How do I mail TextView data on button click in Android app?

Tags: java, android, button, jakarta-mail

First of all, I am pretty new to Android and NFC both, although I am quiet accustomed with Java. I am making an NFC android application as my Major Project in which I would like to **mail** a certain list(displaying the results) **on the click of a button**.

Can someone help me with the code or direct me to some step-by-step tutorials for this...

Thanks in anticipation..!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use an `Intent` to launch an application capable of sending mail and pass your data with it:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
            "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "EXTRA_SUBJECT");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Comment: @ DroidBender Does the Chooser automatically display the relevant apps..?? And how do I pass the TextView data as Email text..??

Answer (score 0):

```
In above code just add this line:
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content of the email");
```

Comment: @Imran can you please tell me how to modify this code to take in Text Body and subject from another activity... And also tell if some Manifest modifications are required.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want to get body of email from another activity then pass edittext text in intent from activity where your edittext is and receive it to another activity where your intent is

for example
Activity A

EditText bodyText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.body_text);
EditText subjectText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.subject_text);

String emailBody=bodyText.getText().toString().trim();
String emailSubject=subjectText.getText().toString().trim();

Intent inte=new Intent(A.this,B.class);
inte.putExtra("body",bodyText);
inte.purExtra("subject",emailSubject);
startActivity(inte);

and in Activity B receive the intent like this,

Intent intent=getIntent();
String bodyText=intent.getExtras().getString("body");
String subjectText=intent.getExtras().getString("subject");

Intent emailInte=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,Uri.fromParts("mailto","xyz@gmail.com",null));
emailInte.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subjectText);
emailInte.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bodyText);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailInte,"Send email using"));
```

Comment: I've made some changes to my code using Android intent and I'm now getting a fatal error. I've posted a new question with code and LogCat problem log. Please refer and help me out: [New Question Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412029/how-to-mail-textview-data-on-button-click-with-android-intent)